# Magento selects wrong codepool

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, database

```
 $model=Mage::getModel("test_hello/hello");
```

Here I load model like above. My module is in local code pool. Magento gives me warning message like below,

```
`include(Mage/Test/Hello/Model/Hello.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`
```

My config xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Hello>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Test_Hello>
    </modules>
    <globel>
        <models>
            <hello>
                <class>Test_Hello_Model</class>
                 <resourceModel>news_resource</resourceModel>
            </hello>
             <news_resource>
                <class>Test_Hello_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <hello>
                        <table>test_hello</table>
                    </hello>
                </entities>
            </news_resource>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <hello>
                <class>Test_Hello_Helper</class>
            </hello>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <hello_setup>
                 <setup>
                    <module>Test_Hello</module>
                </setup>
            </hello_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <hello>
                <class>Test_Hello_Block</class>
            </hello>
        </blocks>
    </globel>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <hello>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_Hello</module>
                    <frontName>helloda</frontName>
                </args>
            </hello>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <hello>
                    <file>hello.xml</file>
                </hello>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

Comment: will u pls add your config.xml code here.

Comment: paste your config.xml code.

Comment: make sure that your module directory permission is 777.

Comment: I've edited my code. Kindly check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined the model alias as"hello" but use "test_hello" in getModel().

It should be "hello/hello".

**To explain what has happened:** Magento doesn't find a model with the alias "test_hello/hello", so it falls back to the `Mage` namespace and the given alias with capitalized letters as module (no, I have never seen a case where this would have been the desired behavior, but this is how it works). This results in `Mage_Test_Hello_Model_Hello as model class name which cannot be found.

**As a general rule:** If Magento tries to load classes from your module with "Mage_" prefix, your module configuration is either incomplete, has errors or is cached with an old version and the configuration cache must be cleared.

Comment: It works @fschmengler

Answer (score 0):

```
<global>
        <models>
            <hello>
                <class>Test_Hello_Model</class>
                 <resourceModel>news_resource</resourceModel>
            </hello>
</global>
```

you have spelling mistake in the global